# Question about automorphisms of simplicial category $\mathbf{\Delta}$

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff, functors

Let $\rho: \mathbf{\Delta} \to \mathbf{\Delta}$ be the functor defined as the identity on objects and by the formula
$$
\rho(f)(i)=n-f(m-i)
$$
for any map $f:[m] \to [n]$, with $0 \leq i \leq m$. Then how to prove $\rho$ is the only non-trivial automorphism of the simplicial category $\mathbf{\Delta}$ ?

I only know any automorphism must map identities to identities, and I tried to use the decomposition of morphism but failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to get started with the problem (maybe you can finish it):

Let $F : \Delta \to \Delta$ be an isomorphism of categories.

The object $[0] \in \Delta$ is the (only) terminal object in $\Delta$. It follows $F([0])=[0]$.

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the object $[n] \in \Delta$ has exactly $n+1$ morphisms $[0] \to [n]$. It follows that there are exactly $n+1$ morphisms $[0]=F([0]) \to F([n])$, and hence $F([n])=[n]$.

Now consider the two morphisms $\delta_0^1,\delta_1^1 : [0] \to [1]$, which we abbreviate by $\delta_0,\delta_1$ for the moment. The isomorphism $F$ maps them to the same set of morphisms, *but their order may change*. If the order stays the same, so $F(\delta_0)=\delta_0$, $F(\delta_1)=\delta_1$, we will prove $F = \mathrm{id}$ below. But if $F(\delta_0)=\delta_1$ and $F(\delta_1)=\delta_0$, consider $G := F \circ \rho$, where the automorphism $\rho$ is defined as in your question. It satisfies $\rho(\delta_0)=\delta_1$ and $\rho(\delta_1)=\delta_0$. But then $G(\delta_0)=\delta_0$ and $G(\delta_1)=\delta_1$. If we have proven $G=\mathrm{id}$, then $F = \rho^{-1}=\rho$.

Therefore, we may assume $F(\delta_0^1)=\delta_0^1$ and $F(\delta_1^1)=\delta_1^1$, and the goal is to prove $F(f)=f$ for every morphism $f : [m] \to [n]$.

The face maps in $\Delta$ are exactly the indecomposable monomorphisms in $\Delta$. And the degeneracy maps are exactly the indecomposable epimorphisms in $\Delta$. It follows that $F$ preserves these types of maps. And we know that they generate all morphisms under composition, so it suffices to look at these.

So for every $n > 0$ we find a permutation $\sigma_n$ of $\{0,\dotsc,n\}$ such that $F(\delta^n_i : [n-1] \to [n]) = \delta^n_{\sigma_n(i)} : [n-1] \to [n]$. (Similarly for the degeneracy maps.)

But these images still satisfy the simplicial identities. So for example, $$\delta^{n+1}_i \circ \delta^n_j = \delta^{n+1}_{j+1} \circ \delta^n_i$$
implies
$$\delta^{n+1}_{\large \sigma_{n+1}(i)} \circ\delta^n_{\large \sigma_n(j)} = \delta^{n+1}_{\large \sigma_{n+1}(j+1)} \circ \delta^n_{\large \sigma_n(i)}.\quad (\ast)$$
The task is to derive $\sigma_n(i)=i$ from this relation as well as our assumption $\sigma_1 = \mathrm{id}_{\{0,1\}}$. I assume that we can simply compute both sides of $(\ast)$ to prove this. I suggest to start with proving $\sigma_2= \mathrm{id}_{\{0,1,2\}}$, and then to use an induction.

Comment: @Siyuan: Could you fill in the details?

Comment: Sorry for my very late response, $\delta_i^{n+1} \circ \delta_j^n = \delta_{j+1}^{n+1} \circ \delta_i^n$ is true when $i \leq j$. Assume that $\sigma_{n}(i) = i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$. Let $i=j$ in $(\ast)$, if $\sigma_{n+1}(i) \leq i$, by applying $(\ast)$ we know $\sigma_{n+1}(i) = i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n+1$.

Comment: If $\sigma_{n+1}(i) > i$, by applying $(\ast)$ and $\delta_j^{n+1} \circ \delta_i^n = \delta_{i}^{n+1} \circ \delta_{j-1}^n$ we know $\sigma_{n+1}(i) = i+1$ and $\sigma_{n+1}(i+1) = i$, on the other hand there is an identity of degeneracy maps $s_j^{n} \circ s_i^{n+1} = s_{i}^{n} \circ s_{j+1}^{n+1}$ when $i \leq j$. Let $j=i+1$ and map it by $F$, then we get $\sigma_{n+1}(i+1) = i+2$, which leads to a contradiction. Thus $\sigma_{n+1}(i) = i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n+1$, and by induction we have $\sigma_n =id$.